# Verify if certain divs contains a specific class

Tags: javascript, html

In my project there are 10 divs with the class .content like this:

```
<div class="content">Example</div>
```

I have already wroted a function that will atribute an .active class to my divs and they will appear like this:

```
<div class="content active">Example</div>
```

Now i need a function than will verify if all my divs with the class .content have the class .active too.

Thank you.

Comment: `yourelement.classList.contains('yourclass')` Simple as that.

Comment: Use [*Array.from*](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the *div.content* NodeList to array, then use [*every*](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to see if every div also has *.active*. `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.content')).every(div => div.classList.contains('active'))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(e => {
  console.log(e.classList.contains("active"));
});
```

```html
  <div class="content active">Example</div>
  <div class="content">Example</div>
  <div class="content active">Example</div>
  <div class="content">Example</div>
  <div class="content active">Example</div>
```

Here is an example.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the list of div and check

```
var contentDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("content")
for (var i = 0; i < contentDivs.length; i++) {
  var div = contentDivs[i];
  if (div.classList.contains("active")) {
    // do something 
  } else {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the elements to check in the following function :

```
function verify(elementX, nameOfStyleToCheck) {
  return elementX.classList.contains(nameOfStyleToCheck);
}
```